# Do simple products need an individual url_key set?

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite, simple-product

As we had controversial opinions about this on our project, I'd like to ask the question here for another opinion (or two):

For Magento2, should we set url keys for simple products? Which of the three options is best?

**a)** use a unique *url key* for each simple product

**b)** use the same *url key* for all simples of one configurable

**c)** leave the *url key* empty for simple products

Our setup:

- We have one page per configurable in our shop.
- all simples of one configurable have the same name

My findings:

- Configurables **must** have a unique url key
- It is possible to add the same url key to multiple simple products
- If I do not set a url key for a configurable, it is derived from the "name" attribute automatically
- It is perfectly fine to set **no** url key for a simple. The simple product will then have no attribute record for the attribute type "url_key".
- M2 does not seem to automatically increment the url key, if the (automatically derived) url key exists already

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, the Url Key must be unique for each product.

Similar to Magento1, Magento2 doesn't append a unique number to the URL Key to make it unique if the same URL key exists already. It throws an error in that case.

**For Every Product:** 
If you leave the url key empty, Magento will use the product title to create a URL key. If two products have the same product title, then creation of the second product will fail with the error message `URL key for specified store already exists.`

**As per your your setup:**

All simples of one configurable have the same name like "Shirt"; so all configurable and simple products will have the same name. 
But each simple product will have configurable attribute variations like "Color and Size". So it will be like:

```
Main Configurable Product: Shirt (URL - shirt)

Four Simple Shirt Products:

Shirt Black L (URL - shirt-black-l)

Shirt Black M (URL - shirt-black-m)

Shirt White L (URL - shirt-white-l)

Shirt White M (URL - shirt-white-m)
```

You can set up the URL key like in the example above. As it is required to use a **unique** URL key (no need to mention that, if the Title is unique, then it will be successfully derived automatically from the title).

**Find my comments on your findings:**

- Configurables must have a unique url key  - **YES**
- It is possible to add the same url key to multiple simple products - **NO**
- If I do not set a url key for a configurable, it is derived from the "name" attribute automatically - **YES if Title is unique other wise error will show**
- It is perfectly fine to set no url key for a simple. The simple product will then have no attribute record for the attribute type "url_key". - **NO**
- M2 does not seem to automatically increment the url key, if the (automatically derived) url key exists already - **YES**

Comment: @dan please select answer and upvote if this help you.

Comment: Hi @Pankaj Preek, - thank you for your post. I appreciate that you tried to help, and I understand that I should upvote your post if it helps me. I have researched and experimented a lot before I posted this question here. Unfortunately, some of your findings are the opposite of what I found out. I actually set the url key of simple products programmatically to <nothing> upon creation. It works. I now wonder why you cannot, while I can. So far, it rather confused me than helping me; my apologies.